# Threading issue with Dispatcher.Invoke and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: wpf

Acording to my understanding Dispatcher.Invoke and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke executes on UI thread, The only difference is That Invoke is synchronous and BeginInvoke  is asynchronous.My problem is when i use this code

```
 EDisc.App.Current.Dispatcher.
              Invoke(
                              DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate
                              {
                                  context = NavigationManager.CurrentPage.DataContext;
                              }));
```

Value of context is returned. However with the below code

```
 EDisc.App.Current.Dispatcher.
              BeginInvoke(
                              DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate
                              {
                                  context = NavigationManager.CurrentPage.DataContext;
                              }));
```

Context is null and i get an InvalidOperation Exception saying "

The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.I am calling this from a WCF service which is executing with UseSynchronizationContext = false .Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Comment: What is the type of `EDisc.App`?

Comment: it is the class name of Applicaion Object .Application x:Class="EDisc.App"

Answer (score 2):

Both `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke` will end up calling an internal method called `BeginInvokeImpl` to do the work. The difference is that `Invoke` then waits for the operation to complete before returning.

And there's one other difference: if you are already on the UI thread *and* you're using `DispatcherPriority.Send` `Invoke` will actually invoke the method directly without going via `BeginInvokeImpl`, meaning that the operation is processed without going via the message queue. (If you're not using `Send` then any other messages already queued up with higher property than your operation will get processed first.)

But since you're presumably not on the UI thread here - you're on some WCF callback - that special case won't apply. So `Invoke` ends up calling into the same underlying implementation as `BeginInvoke`.

From the information you've provided, I'd have to guess that there's a missing detail somewhere here. The code you've shown should work fine, unless perhaps you have multiple UI threads in your application, and the page that happens to be in `CurrentPage` belongs to different threads from time to time.

If you do have multiple UI threads, then the approach you're using - pushing everything through the current `Application` object's dispatcher - isn't going to work, because you'll have multiple dispatchers. You'd need to get the right dispatcher for whichever UI element you're planning to touch.

Incidentally, one way you might accidentally end up with multiple UI threads is if you construct a UI object (e.g. a Page) on some worker thread or callback. Is it possible that you've done that somewhere?

Comment: I have used backgroudthread to do dataintensive operation. however, whenever i am calling the code in question,my Ui is fully responsive(no background thread is involved).